# Groupby by different columns

Tags: pandas, datetime, group-by

I have a dataframe nf as follows :

```
    StationID   DateTime    Channel Count
0   1   2017-10-01 00:00:00 1   1
1   1   2017-10-01 00:00:00 1   201
2   1   2017-10-01 00:00:00 1   8
3   1   2017-10-01 00:00:00 1   2
4   1   2017-10-01 00:00:00 1   0
5   1   2017-10-01 00:00:00 1   0
6   1   2017-10-01 00:00:00 1   0
7   1   2017-10-01 00:00:00 1   0
```

.......... and so on
I want to groupby values by each hour and for each channel and StationID

Output Req

```
Station ID DateTime       Channel    Count  
1   2017-10-01 00:00:00    1          232
1   2017-10-01 00:01:00    1          23
2   2017-10-01 00:00:00    1          244...
```

...... and so on

Comment: Hi, It is not a duplicate as the values I need should be also grouped by each hour .

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregate `sum`, for `datetime`s with floor by `hour`s add [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) - it set `minute`s and `second`s to `0`:

```
print (df)
   StationID             DateTime  Channel  Count
0          1  2017-12-01 00:00:00        1      1
1          1  2017-12-01 00:00:00        1    201
2          1  2017-12-01 00:10:00        1      8
3          1  2017-12-01 10:00:00        1      2
4          1  2017-10-01 10:50:00        1      0
5          1  2017-10-01 10:20:00        1      5
6          1  2017-10-01 08:10:00        1      4
7          1  2017-10-01 08:00:00        1      1

df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])

df1 = (df.groupby(['StationID', df['DateTime'].dt.floor('H'), 'Channel'])['Count']
        .sum()
        .reset_index() 
        )
print (df1)
   StationID            DateTime  Channel  Count
0          1 2017-10-01 08:00:00        1      5
1          1 2017-10-01 10:00:00        1      5
2          1 2017-12-01 00:00:00        1    210
3          1 2017-12-01 10:00:00        1      2

print (df['DateTime'].dt.floor('H'))
0   2017-12-01 00:00:00
1   2017-12-01 00:00:00
2   2017-12-01 00:00:00
3   2017-12-01 10:00:00
4   2017-10-01 10:00:00
5   2017-10-01 10:00:00
6   2017-10-01 08:00:00
7   2017-10-01 08:00:00
Name: DateTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But if dates are not important, only hours use [`hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html):

```
df2 = (df.groupby(['StationID', df['DateTime'].dt.hour, 'Channel'])['Count']
        .sum()
        .reset_index() 
        )
print (df2)
   StationID  DateTime  Channel  Count
0          1         0        1    210
1          1         8        1      5
2          1        10        1      7
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DateTime', freq='"H'), 'Channel', 'StationID')['Count'].sum()
```